# Google API with GoogleSignIn - Error 401 - unauthorized

Tags: android, google-api

I'm sitting on this thing for nearly a week, and couldn't find any documentation that actually explains how to connect a GoogleSignIn to Google API...

I am trying to authenticate users with Google (by using the GoogleSignIn framework), and afterward read a specific calendar. A similar approach on iOS worked "out of the box", now I'm trying to do the same for Android.

I authenticate users by using:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"))
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(), gso);
signIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent signInIntent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
  }
});
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());
if (account == null) {
  setSignInVisible(true);
} else {
  setSignInVisible(false);
  if (account.getIdToken() != null) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
}
```

And later, trying to access the Calendar API by using:

```
Calendar HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
GoogleSignInAccount gsia = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());
GoogleCredential gc = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(gsia.getIdToken());
mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, gc)
                    .setApplicationName("MyApp")
                    .build();
Events events = mService.events().list(CalendarActivity._dataStore.getConfigString(CalendarActivity.instance.getString(R.string.config_google_calendar_key)))
                    .setTimeMin(dtFourDaysBack)
                    .setTimeMax(dtTwoMonthFuture)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .execute();
```

But, the execute results in 401- unauthorized error...
Am I doing anything wrong?
It is important to mention I do get user information from the account object (I see the email, I get a token, etc.)

Comment: have you add `SHA1` key in google api developer console ?

Comment: Yes, but it seems like the GoogleCredential maps to a "web client" (based on something I tried - I tried creating a GoogleAccountCredential based on audience, and it gave a different error for any client_id I used, except the one for the web client, which returned the 401 - unauthorized (the other said there is an issue with the audience)

Comment: Post your error log cat?

Comment: That's the only thing that is printed there in between the execute to the error popping (it prints about 4 times) - pretty sure it's unrelated: 04-18 01:45:11.724  W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: I just debugged everything in between the posted code -- nothing pops in the log...

Comment: I think you are using without any thread synchronization. put your calendar code in AsyncTask class

Comment: are you added  GET_ACCOUNTS , WRITE_CALENDAR ,READ_CALENDAR permissions in manifest.

Comment: The code is running through a class that extends AsyncTask, within the "doInBackground" overload, and I have all of these in the manifest.

I am not sure if it is relevant, I also use Firestore, and firestore calls complete successfully (reading items only my google user has access to)

Comment: btw @GParekar why do I actually need these permissions for the Google API call? (I added the permissions for a different reason, I actually want to add events from the shared Google Calendar I created to the local one, but I don't see a reason why I'll need these permissions to read from the Google Calendar API..)

Comment: I got it working, none of these permissions are actually necessary for it.  The only thing that is necessary is to request the right scope from the GoogleSignIn.

Comment: An update, although the GET_ACCOUNTS permission was not required for the up to date devices I tested on, for older ones it was required, so I added it (the error for it is different)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved the issue, and I hope this will help all those who suffer from an unexplainable 401 - Unauthorized error.

The issue was the generation of the Credentials.
The way it should be created is:

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };
final GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());
GoogleAccountCredential mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                       mainActivity.instance, Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                                      .setSelectedAccountName(account.getAccount().name)
                                      .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

Notice the usage of the Credentials. It is not `GoogleCredentials`. The thing I couldn't find anywhere is the need to `setSelectedAccountName` which I got to by experimenting (too bad it took me about a week to try that one...).

When you're implementing it, make sure to make it clean (use the `account` object only if it's not `null`, etc.

Good luck to us all...

Comment: Thanx a lot! I too have been struggling with this for over a week. There are so many other SO questions where your answer would be relevant.

Comment: Maybe you could also mention that the EMAIL scope needs to be requested (even though its there in the code in your question) otherwise getAccount returns null - took me some time before I could figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

May be your are trying to call your calendar code without any sync process. Try following code that integrate google calendar.
An asynchronous task that handles the Google Calendar API call. Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.

```
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;

        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
            DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
            Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .setTimeMin(now)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .execute();
            List<Event> items = events.getItems();

            for (Event event : items) {
                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                    // the start date.
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                eventStrings.add(
                        String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
            }
            return eventStrings;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
                //"No results returned
            } else {
                //Data retrieved using the Google Calendar API
            }
        }
}
```

For more detail please check [google documentation description](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/android)

Comment: It is implemented that way, I didn't mention it above just not to diverge attention to unimportant things like my UI responsiveness, or ads loading code etc. 

Now, that just for my curiosity - is there any relation between Async and authorization for Google API?
I hope there is not... but I won't be surprised if someone decided it's a good idea to enforce that...